# Does spring data handle “consistent request” for mongo db?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data, concurrent-programming

Here [consistent request in Mongo](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/java-concurrency/) I found how to handle consistent request in java code.

```
DB db...;
db.requestStart();
try {
   db.requestEnsureConnection();

   code....
} finally {
   db.requestDone();
}
```

Does spring-data cares about it. Or I should do it manually as using plain java driver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In spring data to execute with in same connection, you should use `mongoTemplate.executeInSession(DbCallback action)`. Please take a look at the [Spring documentation Section 5.1.1 about Execution Callback](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-document/docs/1.0.0.M2/reference/html/).